# Calling Show() of embedded form should show parent form

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl, tform

I use embedded forms in my application and I was trying something like this:

At designtime the form is a normal form which don't know anything about embedding/docking.
With a ButtonClick I can make the form visible by calling the Show() method of the form. 
At runtime it can happen that the form gets docked into another form and becomes an embedded form.
When I press the Button for showing the form again (which is now embedded) nothing happens because 
I have to call Show() for the form which contains the embedded form now.

I am lookin for a method to force showing the parent form when the Show() method of the embedded form is called. I could handle this by checking the existance of a parent form before calling Show() but I don't want to include this specific handling.

I would prefer to do this handling in the parent form wich gets notified when a form is docked.

The Show() method only sets the Visible property to true (RAD Studio Help), so I don't think that a message is fired ...?

Do you know a method to realize something like this?

**Edit**

I want to put some information about my application because I guess that it is more a designing problem than a programming problem.

The application uses several plugins to adapt to the connected hardware. The exe provides a drag&dock environment and contains a base class for dockable forms. The plugins don't have any knowledge about the docking implementation. By creating a dockable form and embedding a form from the plugin the plugin form becomes dockable. This is the reason why I want do get the parent form shown when somewhere the method Show() of the embedded form is called.

Comment: Calling `Show` doesn't do what you want. What you want to do requires something to walk the parent chain to find the top level form, and call `Show` on that. You want the top level form shown but want to avoid walking the parent chain. Are you prepared for the possibility that what you are asking cannot be done?

Comment: Once the child is embedded, The parent could hook to the child form WindowProc by sub-classing it and checking for WM_SHOW etc messages. (Id better use `GetParentForm <> nil` and simply show it).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes I was prepared for this :) I was hoping that the vcl has a mechanism that I don't know yet.

Comment: @kobik: Does WM_SHOW gets fired even when OnShow isn't triggered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a common ancestor for your embedded forms or even for all forms in the application, and then derive your forms from it:

```
type
  TEmbeddedForm = class(TForm)
  public
    procedure Show;
  end;

procedure TEmbeddedForm.Show;
var
  ParentForm: TCustomForm;
begin
  inherited Show;
  ParentForm := GetParentForm(Self);
  if ParentForm <> Self then
  begin
    // Form is Embedded
    Update;        
    ParentForm.Show;
    // You might alternatively consider to send custom 
    // message to the Parent form, and let it decide what to do e.g.
    // SendMessage(ParentForm.Handle, CM_MY_EMBEDED_FORM_SHOW, 0, 0);
  end;
end;
```

Then when you call:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // MyEmbeddedForm is derived from TEmbeddedForm 
  MyEmbeddedForm.Align := alClient;
  MyEmbeddedForm.BorderStyle := bsNone;

  MyEmbeddedForm.Parent := Form3.Panel1;
  MyEmbeddedForm.Show;
end;
```

`Form3` is showing.

---

Another option (which I only confirmed with Spy++) is to intercept `WM_CHILDACTIVATE` or `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` in the `TEmbeddedForm`. it is sent to it when the child form is calling `TEmbeddedForm.Show`, and act accordingly i.e. `GetParentForm(Self).Show`.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not this what I want.
My application gets extended by several plugins (bpls and dlls) at runtime. By embedding forms (wich are contained in those packages) I can give them a special functionality if I want. When I put the baseclass in several bpls and load them it doesn't work as is known.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the last part. if you use form plugins it **is** advisable to use a common ancestor e.g. `TPluginForm`. Please update you question with the relevant information because now I'm not sure what you want.

Comment: I know. This was my first approach some months ago. But it is not possible to have to bpls loaded paralel when both contain the same module. So I discarded it. But I am thinking about using only dlls to avoid this problem with the bpls.

Comment: @KeremD It seems that what you really want is to call `Show` and have the ultimate parent form show. Is that correct?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm not sure what you mean with ultimate form, the top of the parent chain perhaps? Then you are right...

Comment: That's what ultimate means. So far as I can tell, I am afraid to tell you that what you are asking for is not possible and that unfortunately you will have to give up. Since you won't accept anything less than a single call to `Show` on the embedded form, you have no other choice.

Comment: Like I have written it after your first comment I was prepared for this. A single call would be the optimal way. I will have to review the plugin concept.Thank you

Comment: GetParentForm will not ever return nil for a TCustomForm.

Comment: @kobik: I don't know how it works in Delphi but in C++ it seems like I can't override `Show`, because its declared as `HIDEBASE` and not as `HIDEBASEDYNAMIC`

Comment: You don't override it. you re-liniment it. see the Delphi source I posted, there is no `override`. I call `inherited Show;` in the new method.

Comment: Ok sorry, I interpreted the code wrong. I have tried this and think that in my case inheriting all "plugin forms" from a base class with this funcionality makes sense. I accept this answer and thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SetFocus` instead of `Show` on the embedded form.

This will enforce showing of the parent form too.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't confirm this.
Also I have to call Show() first otherwise I get an error(Not visible control cant't get focus OSLT).

Comment: It requires that both forms are shown once before. That can be solved by setting `Visible = True` in the designer.

Comment: You are right. But when I close the parent form and call this again I have the same problem. Thank you.